# Assembly MASM adding multiplication result to sum

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, masm, multiplication

I have a little problem with finding a way to add the multiplication result to the sum. Assuming that we can only use registers (no memory variables), I am not sure about how I can be able to accomplish this. For example, if I want to compute this expression:

```
; 2013 * 365 + 765

mov ax, 365
mov bx, 2013
mul bx ; 2013 * 365
; The result would be DX:AX where EAX = 00003619 EDX = 0000000B 

mov cx, 765
; Now I am stuck here. I am not sure how can I add the result of multiplication
; to cx since it's DX:AX. Also, just to remind you, I am not allowed to use 
; any variables.
; Any help would be appreciated!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `cx` to the doubleword in `dx:ax`:

```
add ax,cx   ; ax += cx
adc dx,0    ; dx += the carry from the previous addition (0 or 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there any way to "squeeze" dx:ax into one register? For example, to store the final result in EAX so I can call writeDec to print the result.

Comment: `shl eax,16` / `mov ax,dx` / `rol eax,16` (could be simplified a bit if it's known that the high word of `eax` is clear).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! With shifting and rotating bits it seems so much simpler. It's quite strange that I wasn't introduced with `shl` and `rol.`